# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable - spark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, typeerror

i'm getting below error while executing the mentioned 'join' statement. i'm using pyspark setup. Any change required in the join statement or code.

**TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

```
df11 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("s3://mybucket/file1.csv")
df22 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("s3://mybucket/file2.csv")
df11.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
df22.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")
df1 = spark.sql( "select * from table1" )
df2 = spark.sql( "select * from table2" )

df_d = df1.join(df2, df1.NO == df2.NO, 'left').filter(F.isnull(df2.NO)).select(df1.NO,df1.NAME,df1.LAT,df1.LONG, F.lit('DELETE').alias('FLAG'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the col names as string like this, it should work

```
df_d = df1.join(df2, df1['NO'] == df2['NO'], 'left').filter(F.isnull(df2['NO'])).select(df1['NO'],df1['NAME'],df1['LAT'],df1['LONG'], F.lit('DELETE').alias('FLAG'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help to add new column from the list of existing column

```
for col_name in partition_key_list:
    print(col_name)
    #df_final_recs_i_u_n = df_final_recs_i_u_n.withColumn(f"{col_name}_partition_by", df_final_recs_i_u_n.date_tgt)
    df_final_recs_i_u_n=df_final_recs_i_u_n.withColumn(f"{col_name}_partition_by",df_final_recs_i_u_n[f"{col_name}_tgt"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the temporary view you can use Spark SQL to create the final dataframe. Please check the screenshot below:

[image]

Relevant SQL:

```
spark.sql("select table1.NO, table1.NAME, table1.LAT, table1.LONG, 'DELETE' as FLAG  from table1 left join table2 on table1.NO = table2.NO where table2.NO is null").show()
```